# Solving a system of (more than two) linear inequalities

Tags: haskell, prolog, sympy, sage, inequalities

If I use

```
diophantine(2*x+3*y-5*z-77)
```

I receive this result.

```
{(t_0, -9*t_0 - 5*t_1 + 154, -5*t_0 - 3*t_1 + 77)}
```

Fine so far. However, on occasion one might like to constrain x, y and z to be (say) non-negative. When I use an approach like this<

```
reduce_inequalities([0<=t_0, 0<=-9*t_0 - 5*t_1 + 154, 0<=-5*t_0 - 3*t_1 + 77],[t_0, t_1])
```

I get:

```
NotImplementedError: 
inequality has more than one symbol of interest
```

Does sympy, sage, prolog, haskell or some other freely available product have means for solving systems of linear inequalities that arise in this way.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you look at http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/inequalities.html#inequality-docs ? I never tried it, but seems it should work for linear set of inequalities. If numeric solutions suffice, take a look at `scipy.optimize.linprog()`.

Comment: Can you please post an example of the type of equation you would like to solve.

Comment: Many thanks to @Dietrich for your comment. I had been forgetting to read it until I encountered the question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40441532/how-to-restrict-sympy-finiteset-containing-symbol/40443339#40443339. I hadn't understood that it's possible to solve *systems* of inequalities.

Comment: @Dietrich: Apparently reduce_inequalities can't handle more than one symbol.

Comment: @asmeurer: Thanks for responding. I've included the Diophantine equation.

Answer (score 3):

To reason about **integers** in Prolog, you can use your Prolog system's **CLP(FD) constraints**.

The exact details differ slightly between different Prolog systems. Please see your system's manual for more information, and also [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) for related questions.

In your case, we can start by simply **posting** the constraint:

```
?- 2*X + 3*Y - 5*Z #= 77.
2*X+3*Y#=5*Z+77.
```

In this case, and as for all pure Prolog programs, the system's answer is declaratively *equivalent* to the original query. This does not help a lot here: The system has only slightly rewritten the original constraint.

You can constrain this *further*, for example with:

```
?- 2*X + 3*Y - 5*Z #= 77,
   [X,Y,Z] ins 0..sup.
X in 0..sup,
2*X+3*Y#=5*Z+77,
Y in 0..sup,
Z in 0..sup.
```

As requested, this additional goal constrains the variables to non-negative integers. The system's answer still does not help a lot.

You can use `label/1` to search for concrete **solutions**. However, this so-called *labeling* requires that all domains be *finite*, and so we currently get:

```
?- 2*X + 3*Y - 5*Z #= 77,
   Vs = [X,Y,Z],
   Vs ins 0..sup,
   label(Vs).
ERROR: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

The good news (in a sense) is that we don't have time to try *all* possibilities in any case. So we might as well restrict ourselves to some finite part of the search space. For example:

```
?- 2*X + 3*Y - 5*Z #= 77,
   Vs = [X,Y,Z],
   Vs ins 0..10 000 000 000 000 000 000,
   label(Vs).
```

With this query, you get concrete **integers** as solutions:

```
X = 0,
Y = 29,
Z = 2,
Vs = [0, 29, 2] ;
X = 0,
Y = 34,
Z = 5,
Vs = [0, 34, 5] ;
X = 0,
Y = 39,
Z = 8,
Vs = [0, 39, 8] ;
X = 0,
Y = 44,
Z = 11,
Vs = [0, 44, 11] ;
etc.
```

Since you are reasoning over *linear* constraints, CLP(Q) may also be worth a try.