# Check if a system of inequalities entails another system of equalities?

Tags: python, matlab, prolog

I have a system of inequalities, but the problem is all of the terms in the system are unassigned variables (edit: all variables are representing natural numbers). Like I want to give the system rules like:

```
    a + b >= f + h
    f + b >= d + e
    d + b >= a + c
```

and then ask the system if a query like

```
    d + e >= f + g
```

must be true. Does anyone know how to do this in matlab or python or even prolog?

Comment: Over which domain are you reasoning? Integers, natural numbers, Booleans?

Comment: You mean that the system says "true" if the query is the *logical entailment* of the "theory"?

Comment: all the symbols are natural numbers, ill update the question to include that, thanks mat.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem yes. (assuming that theory == the rules I am giving it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have clarified, you are reasoning over **natural numbers**.

The particular case you show is an example of **Presburger arithmetic**, which is a decidable fragment of arithmetic. There are several **theorem provers** for Presburger arithmetic available, written in Prolog and also in other languages.

Using such provers, you can for example show that the fourth equality is *not* entailed by the preceding three:

```
?- valid(a + b >= f + h /\
         f + b >= d + e /\
         d + b >= a + c ==>
         d + e >= f + g).
false.
```

Here is an explicit **counterexample**:

```
?- solution(a + b >= f + h /\
            f + b >= d + e /\
            d + b >= a + c /\
            not(d + e >= f + g)).
a=0.
b=0.
f=0.
h=0.
d=0.
e=0.
c=0.
g=1.
```

---

Alternatively, with Prolog, you can for example use constraint logic programming over **integers** or **rational numbers**, abbreviated as [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) and [clpq](/questions/tagged/clpq) respectively, to search for counterexamples.

For instance, in the case you show, and using CLP(Q):

```
?- { A + B >= F + H,
     F + B >= D + E,
     D + B >= A + C,
     D + E < F + G }.
{_1692>0, ...}.
```

This answer shows (since CLP(Q) is *complete*) that a counterexample exists over **Q**, but does not tell us whether the formula is entailed over the *integers* or *natural numbers*. However, *if* this query had failed, then we would have known that no counterexample exists over Q *and hence* not over N, meaning that the last inequality would indeed be entailed over N.

To search for counterexamples over N, and even over *integers*, with constraint logic programming, you can use **CLP(FD)**. For example, you can *post* the constraints that a counterexample must satisfy:

```
?- A + B #>= F + H #/\
   F + B #>= D + E #/\
   D + B #>= A + C #/\
   #\ (D + E #>= F + G),
```

You can search for concrete solutions via *labeling*. However, this requires that all domains be *finite*. We can start for example with `0..2`, and try increasingly larger domains. This strategy is *complete*: *If* there is a counterexample, we *will* find it in this way. If, on the other hand, no counterexample exists, consider that we cannot draw any conclusion regarding the formula's validity from the fact that we have not yet found one.

In this case, we are lucky and soon find several counterexamples:

```
?- A + B #>= F + H #/\
   F + B #>= D + E #/\
   D + B #>= A + C #/\
   #\ (D + E #>= F + G),
   Vs = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H],
   Vs ins 0..2,
   label(Vs).
A = B, B = F, F = H, H = D, D = E, E = C, C = 0,
G = 1,
Vs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] ;
A = B, B = F, F = H, H = D, D = E, E = C, C = 0,
G = 2,
Vs = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0] ;
A = F, F = H, H = D, D = E, E = C, C = 0,
B = G, G = 1,
Vs = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0] ;
A = F, F = D, D = E, E = C, C = 0,
B = H, H = G, G = 1,
Vs = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1] ;
A = F, F = H, H = D, D = E, E = C, C = 0,
B = 1,
G = 2,
Vs = [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0] .
```

In summary, I suggest a combination of:

- **theorem provers** over Presburger arithmetic
- **CLP(FD)**
- **CLP(Q)**
- and possibly **further methods**

to find counterexamples or proofs of such entailments.

Note that this quickly becomes **undecidable** in general, but it is decidable over linear formulas.

Comment: Would you please take a look at my question, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270160/solving-a-system-of-more-than-two-linear-inequalities

Comment: @BillBell: I have looked at it and cannot help with sympy or sage. Would you like  to have an answer in terms of CLP(Q) or CLP(FD), using Prolog to solve this? If so, please adapt the tags and clarify this in the question.

Comment: Thank you, yes. I have added the requested tag. Until I had read this question, a Prolog solution had not occurred to me.

Comment: I have added and answer which I hope helps you to solve your task. Please see my profile page for more resources about Prolog. I hope you find them useful!

Comment: I can't get your code in your first text block to work. Are you using gprolog?

Comment: For the first block, I used a theorem prover for Presburger arithmetic, written in Prolog. It is available from [https://www.metalevel.at/presprover/](https://www.metalevel.at/presprover/). For the second block, you can use any Prolog system that provides CLP(Q), such as SICStus Prolog for example.